# Как передать переменное значение адреса ячейки найденное функцией ячейка() по условию в Range() VBA?

Tags: vba

Help me!
Есть процедура, которая устанавливает курсор на ячейку С2 и заменяет значение в ней полученное формулой, на просто значение.
Как передавать в Rang переменный адрес ячейки (меняется от условий расчета на листе эксель через функцию ячейка())?

```
Sub Formulas_To_Values_Selection()
    Range("C2").Select
    Dim smallrng As Range
    For Each smallrng In Selection.Areas
        smallrng.Value = smallrng.Value
    Next smallrng
End Sub
```

Comment: А чё так сложно-то? всё ж в одну строку делается. И выделять её не нужно. *Как передавать в Rang переменный адрес ячейки* Добавить параметр и передавать нужный адрес.

Comment: Весь смысл в выделении заранее не известной ячейки в массиве. Адрес получается в результате расчета... В ячейке записана формула ( в данном случае в С2), а надо чтобы осталось только значение.

Comment: Зачем выделять?

Comment: Не понял... т.е. ты кликаешь по ячейке, и хочешь, чтобы именно в ней формула заменилась на значение? Ну тогда это нужно в Worksheet_SelectionChange рисовать... а заодно организовать флаг, чтобы Excel понимал, когда менять, а когда нет.

Comment: В том то и дело, что кликать не хочется. Курсор выставляется по рассчитанному адресу и заменяет там формулу на значение в определенные промежутки времени ( раз в час например)

Comment: Вообще задача такая: Есть таблица. данные которой пересчитываются  формулами в зависимости от периодически поступающих значений. Надо сохранять историю изменений. Поэтому формулы надо превращать в значения + добавлять момент времени когда это произошло. Вся работа должна быть автоматизирована. ;)

Comment: Как понять, какие формулы заменять, а какие оставлять? Составьте небольшой пример, опишите задачу точнее, ибо то, что в заголовке уже не совпадает с тем, что описано в предыдущем примечании.

Comment: заменяются все формулы за период: раз в час все расчетные значения записываются в стек.

Comment: >> *раз в час все расчетные значения записываются в стек* - А формулы при чем?

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации (если я верно понял задачу).

В ячейку B1 пишем формулу, например

```
B1=A1+1
```

В ячейку С1 пишем слово "fix"

Растягиваем на B1:C1 до B10:C10.

В модуль листа пишем

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 3 And Target.Row <= 10 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value
    Target.Value = Now
End If
End Sub
```

Изменяем значения в A1:A10. Значения в B1:B10 меняются (пересчитываются).

Кликаем по любой одной ячейке в диапазоне C1:C10. В эту ячейку записывается текущая дата-время, а значение в соотв. ячейке колонки B фиксируется. Теперь изменение в колонке A не будет изменять значение в колонке B.

Программное выделение ячейки (например, `cells(7,3).select`) также вызовет срабатывание метода и фиксацию значения.

Если выделено несколько ячеек (руками или программно) - фиксация не выполняется.

Сейчас при повторном клике в колонке С время в ней будет меняться. Можно добавить проверку на то, что значение в колонке С не является датой (или что там присутствует изначальное "fix"), и если там дата - не выполнять операцию.